# Creating my own scenario from TeamTreeHouse.com Example throwing error.

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I am trying to create my own example from the videos to get a better comprehension of the examples and lessons. During building my own I am getting two errors. The first one is:

```
    status = input('Are you single or married?: '.lower())
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'single' is not defined
```

The second one is:

```
    except ValueError:
         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code is:

```
print ('When entering numbers, do not use commas or periods''\n')
salary = int(input('What is your annual salary before taxes?'))

status = input('Are you single or married?: '.lower())
if status == ('single'):
    status = (status)
elif status == 'married':
    status = ('married')
except ValueError:
    print('Sorry I did not understand your input')


else:
    print('You answered that you are {} making {} a year').format(status, salary)
```

I have watched the videos over an re-read my notes but I think because I am trying to build my own example that I am missing something simple that is not in the vides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error, that's because you're using python 2. You should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. `input()` only works for number inputs.

About your `SyntaxError`, it's because you did an `except` without a `try` statement before it, I think you're looking for the `else` statement.

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
print ('When entering numbers, do not use commas or periods''\n')
salary = input('What is your annual salary before taxes?')

status = raw_input('Are you single or married?: ').lower() 
# put .lower() outside if you want the input to be lowercase instead of the question with lowercase letters.

if status != 'single' and status != 'married':
    print('Sorry I did not understand your input')
else:
    print('You answered that you are {} making {} a year').format(status, salary)
```

(I haven't tested it but I hope it works)

Comment: omg youre right! I am sorry lol, I just bough a MacBook and I forgot they come with python 2.x and not 3.x. I will try this and let you know asap!

Comment: @YepramYeransian You're welcome! Please be sure to accept my answer and upvote it :)

Comment: it worked, thank you. I need to figure out how to upgrade my python on mac as I am use to my work laptop which is windows with python 3.x

Comment: @YepramYeransian You can download Python 3.x from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/